# Event Viewer spammed with event 1309 (HttpException) due to illegal URL from IIS ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, exception, iis

I host a website that provides public API access for my customers to track their orders with an order number. I have allowed them to use both POST or GET (with URI parameter) to pass the order number to me. Some of them however wrote careless codes that passes illegal chars (asterisk, colon or incorrectly encoded asian characters), like this `https://mycompany.com/tracking/orderno:ODR12345` which causes IIS to throw exception:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
 at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

I have inherited Application_Error method to log this exception. But it still gets thrown as a 400 Bad Request error to user browser and leave an Event 1309 in my event viewer, hence spamming the log with it.

I know I can turn off illegal-chars-exam from Web.config universally but that's a security risk. I just want to be able to handle this exception myself: capture it, log it my own way, provide useful response to user and then suppress it so it doesn't pollute my system log. How can I do this?

- UPDATE

Lex gave me an idea to rewrite the URL. What I think is, I can put the parameter into the query string instead of leaving it a part of the path, so that dangerous path error will disappear. I then wrote the following rule:

`<rule name="TrackingRewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="/tracking/(.*)" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="tracking?querystring={R:1}" />
</rule>`

So that `https://mycompany.com/tracking/orderno:ODR12345` becomes `https://mycompany.com/tracking?querystring=orderno:ODR12345` and the correct action was executed and users gets a 200 response with tracking information. However - after the controller action returned, Applciation_Error call back still gets called with the "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)." exception and system log was added. Breaking into the Applciation_Error call back and printing the `Request.Url` shows the original illegal URL, not the rewritten one. How does one to comprehend this behavior?

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://blog.mathiaskunto.com/2015/02/03/rewrite-url-before-validateinputifrequiredbyconfig-throws-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client-exception/

Comment: @LexLi Indeed it gave me an idea. Can you see my update?